# SQL group by a column yet ignore the duplicated item of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to solve a problem with a situation similar to the following data,

```
company customer pay sequence
a       x        5    1
a       x        6    2
b       x        3    3
b       y        4    4
a       y        2    5
```

And I want to have a result by calculating the summation of the "pay" group by the company, but the duplicated customer will only use once based on the latest sequence. So the expected result is

```
company sum(pay)
a        8
b        7
```

Meaning that, company "a" sum(pay) 8 comes from second row plus with the last row.
And company "b" sum(pay) 7 comes from 3rd and 4th rows. And the 1st row is ignored.

Thus, I use such query (PostgreSQL) to solve the problem,

```
select t2.company,sum(t2.pay) from mytable t2 join (
    select company,customer,max(sequence) as sequence 
    from mytable group by company,customer
) t1 on t1.sequence=t2.sequence group by t2.company
```

I would like to know whether is there any easier way to use the query without subquery as above?

Comment: What is "not easy" about your query?  It seems very reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, you can do this without the `join`, by using the `distinct on` syntax:

```
select t.company, sum(t.pay)
from (select distinct on (company, customer) company, customer, pay
      from mytable
      order by company, customer, sequence desc
     ) t
group by t.company;
```

I prefer the method in the OP because it is standard SQL.  The `distinct on` statement is only in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to use `ROW_NUMBER`, but I don't know if you can say that it is an "easier" way:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY company, customer 
                           ORDER BY sequence DESC) AS RN
  FROM YourTable
)
SELECT company, 
       SUM(pay) AS pay
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY company
ORDER BY company
```

The results are:

```
╔═════════╦═════╗
║ COMPANY ║ PAY ║
╠═════════╬═════╣
║ b       ║   7 ║
║ a       ║   8 ║
╚═════════╩═════╝
```

[And here is](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53bb0/4) an sqlfiddle with a demo for you to try.

Answer (score 0):

Using a windows function is another option, 
I am not sure it's an easier or faster method though. 
In my opionion it can't be done without a subquery.

```
SELECT company,sum(pay)
FROM (
   SELECT *,
          max( sequence ) OVER (partition by company,customer ) max_seq
   FROM table1
) AS t
WHERE sequence = max_seq
GROUP BY company
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f66b3/4